# 2 Pully Atwood Machine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

I'm helping a friend with a few problems from his algebra based physics class and am stumped on this one.

### [image: Double Atwood]

The pulleys are frictionless and massless. The right side of the m1 string is fixed. It wants the acceleration of each mass.
I have the equation for each mass: $$m_1 a_1 = 2T-m_1g $$ $$m_2 a_2 = T-m_2 g$$ I have 2 equations and 3 unknowns, am I missing something? I can solve for an acceleration with respect to the other but is their a way I can solve them independently? I know the length of string is constant but I'm not sure how to incorporate that.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to relate $a_1$ to $a_2$. To do this, think about how far mass $1$ would move if mass $2$ moved some amount. Or think about how much rope would be needed to move mass $1$ compared to mass $2$ over the same distance. Since this is a homework-like problem I will let you think through the rest. This is where your third equation is.